# mstsc.exe uses 25% of CPU (100% of core) - how to analyze/fix this?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, remoteapp

We have Windows Server 2008 R2 that works as a Remote Desktop host. From there, users again have to connect to another RD host using RemoteApp.
Suddenly, mstsc.exe of RemoteApp connection started to use 25% of CPU (100% of one of the cores), causing freezes.

How do we analyze/fix this? Please help.

Comment: Try to limit what is passed through, for example sound.

Comment: Thank you! The problem seems to be a ghost printer (once connected, but now not connected), users tried to print to.
Removed the files from %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\spool\PRINTERS\ and removed the printer afterwards. Seems like it fixed the issue. I don't use this as an answer, because I'm not 100% sure the issue won't come up again.

Comment: In the meantime I have added a more general answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem might be caused by a device driver that misbehaves, either because
it cannot communicate with its device and tries it repeatedly, or for other reasons.

The best advice is to reduce the number of shared devices until the problem
disappears in order to locate the problematic device.

In the case of the poster, it was apparently a printer that once existed
but was still being shared, which had to be completely removed and uninstalled.